# effective methods for "editioning" your software in .net

Tags: .net, architecture

Given a single .net codebase for a piece of software (let's use C# for argument's sake), and I want to break this software down into different editions based on functionality (like a basic edition and an advanced edition), what is the best way to go about this?

Would I have to factor this into my software architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editions are more on the marketing side then on technical side. try to keep it simple as possible. You need to disable some features rather then provide different set of functionalities.